# Can't add GooglePlayServices to libGDX project on IntelliJIdea with google Repository already installed and the correct Android SDK path

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, libgdx, google-play-services

I am trying to add Google Games functionalities to a video game I'm developing. I'm using LibGDX on IntelliJ Idea. The version of LibGDX I'm using (1.2.0) uses gradle-based project.

I've added this to the dependencies section of the project(":android") block on the main build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.8'
```

However, IntelliJ Idea gives me this error when building:

```
Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':android:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.8.
     Required by:
         cg.euler:android:1.0
```

Also, the "compile" line gives me this warning:

```
Dependency on Play Services, but the SDK installation does not have the "Extras > Google Repository" installed. Open the SDK manager and install it.
```

This is what I've checked / tested:

- The configuration of the Android SDK path on the project is correct (I only have one SDK on my computer)
- The Google Repository package is installed on the SDK manager
- The Google Play services package is installed on the SDK manager
- I tried reinstall both Google Reposotory and Google Play library on the SDK manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you play-services dependency version is incorrect , it should be

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
```

Comment: Hahaha..... WOW..... what a noob error :P. Thank you it was exactly that, thank you.